# Why does empty array convert to string?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find an explanation as to why the expression `Boolean(false)+[]` evaluates to `"false"` in JavaScript. I can see that the `+` operator can be concatenation or addition depending on the types or the left and right hand, but can't seem to find a good explanation as to how does the empty array literal `[]` turn into `string` in this case.

I was looking at the following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus
or section "12.8.3 The Addition Operator (+)"

Comment: What's the point of venturing into this kind of code, apart from wanting to make it even more twisted to understand?

Comment: I was writing up an answer, but what @Ivar just posted is more coherent. I might add to look at https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9 which is the type conversion part of the spec, which explains why it coerces arrays to a string, instead of a number for example.

Comment: To add to @Ivar, I assume this decision was made because in most languages, strings are usually represented as an array of chars and so the intuition is that the "middle ground" between a bool and an array is a string.